# IOS - Updating AppBadge Count using local notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, uilocalnotification, remote-notifications

I have a use case where I want to set timely local notifications, which on delivery would fetch unread message count from server through API call and will update the App icon badge based on that number.

So is this use case served by local notifications, or will I have to use remote notifications to send the unread message count to the app?

Comment: You cannot do anything "on delivery" of a local notification. A local notification is a message to the user. Your app doesn't necessarily get any event when it fires.

Comment: This sounds more like a use case for background fetch; this will let you periodically check your server and post a local notification/badge your icon if there are new messages, or you could use a remote notification as you suggest